# Gradle - Exclude Nested Transitive Dependencies

Tags: hibernate, gradle, spring-boot

The below custom boot dependency has a number of transitive dependencies. Few of these transitive dependencies have reference to org.hibernate group. I updated the below in my build.gradle file to exclude the dependency. However it doesn't seem to be removed when I run "gradle dependencies" and view the dependency tree.Should something be modified in order to exclude nested transitive dependencies?

```
compile("com.comp.service:service-boot:3.0.+") {
    exclude group: 'org.hibernate'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `configurations` section:

```
dependencies {
    ....
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.hibernate'
}
```

You can also use `module` to narrow down the exclusion (if `group` alone removes too many transitive dependencies).

sources :

- [how to properly configure gradle build to avoid including log4j and slf4j from the resulting jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033235/how-to-properly-configure-gradle-build-to-avoid-including-log4j-and-slf4j-from-t/40034406#40034406)
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies (#25.4.7)
- http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2012/10/gradle-goodness-exclude-transitive.html

Answer (score 1):

use as below block and i hope its work-

```
    compile("com.comp.service:service-boot:3.0.+") {
     exclude group: 'org.hibernate'
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry , it was a typo. I had used group. I've corrected the original post. This doesn't exclude the dependency.